# How do I subset columns from on data

Tags: r

```html
rankhospital <- function(state = factor(), outcome = factor(), num = factor()) {
        #read data
        caremeasures <- read.csv("D:/data science specialization/course stuff/rprogw3/outcome-of-care-measures.csv", na.strings = "NA", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        
        
        #separate required columns
        requiredOutcomes <- caremeasures[11, 17, 23]
        
        #assign columns names
        names(requiredOutcomes[3]) <- "heart attack"
        names(requiredOutcomes[4]) <- "heart failure"
        names(requiredOutcomes[5]) <- "pneumonia"
        
         
        arrangedData <- order(requiredOutcomes[caremeasures$State == state, c(caremeasures$Hospital.Name, outcome)])
        
        if (num == "best"){
            result <- arrangedData[1, 1]
            return(result)
                
                
        }
        else if (num == "worst"){
            result <- arrangedData[nrow(arrangedData[,1]),1]
            return(result)
            
        }
        else 
            result <- arrangedData[num, 1]
            return(result)
}
```

This code is supposed to return the name of a single hospital that corresponds to the inputs given to the function, yet I'm getting an error stating:

```
Error in requiredOutcomes[caremeasures$State == state, c(caremeasures$Hospital.Name,  : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your data, so I'll project what I think is leading up to the problem.

The reference to `caremeasures[11, 17, 23]` is likely not doing what you need, and it is therefore returning something you aren't expecting. Try it with `caremeasures[,c(11, 17, 23)]`.

I'll try to show what's going on using `mtcars`:

```r
requiredOutcomes <- mtcars[1,2,3]
requiredOutcomes
# [1] 6
requiredOutcomes[1,2]
# Error in requiredOutcomes[1, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Because `mtcars` is a `data.frame`, your `[` indexing uses `[.data.frame` under the hood. This translates something like

```r
# equivalent
mtcars[1, 2]
`[.data.frame`(mtcars, 1, 2)
```

The "arguments" (yes, it's just a regular function) are:

```r
str(formals(`[.data.frame`))
# Dotted pair list of 4
#  $ x   : symbol 
#  $ i   : symbol 
#  $ j   : symbol 
#  $ drop: language if (missing(i)) TRUE else length(cols) == 1
```

which means that your `11, 17, 23` arguments are effectively

```r
`[.data.frame`(requireOutcomes, 11, 17, 23)
```

which is applied to the arguments as

```r
`[.data.frame`(x = requireOutcomes, i = 11, j = 17, drop = 23)
```

Okay, so `x=` makes sense (the data). `i=` gives your row selection (11), and `j=` gives the column selection. However, when R expected a `logical`, then anything that is not zero is considered `TRUE`, so this is effectively

```r
`[.data.frame`(x = requireOutcomes, i = 11, j = 17, drop = TRUE)
```

which completely loses your intent (I suspect) by returning a *scalar* (single value, a vector of length 1 in R). Side note: had you used `0` or `FALSE`, then you would have returned a `data.frame` with 1 row and 1 column.

Here's a method for debugging what's going on so that you are able to find this for yourself next time.

```r
myfunc <- function(x) {
  res <- x[1,2,3]
  return(res[1:3,])
}
myfunc(mtcars)
# Error in res[1:3, ] (from #3) : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Okay, we see the same error. We'll use `debug(myfunc)` (whatever your function name is), though you can achieve similar results by placing `browser()` at a specific place within your function.

```r
debug(myfunc)
myfunc(mtcars)
# debugging in: myfunc(mtcars)
# debug at #1: {
#     res <- x[1, 2, 3]
#     return(res[1:3, ])
# }
# Browse[2]>
```

We're now in R's debugger, giving us step execution tracing. Typing `n` executes the `n`ext line; you can read more of the commands with [`?browser`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/browser.html).

```r
n
# debug at #2: res <- x[1, 2, 3]
# Browse[2]> 
n
# debug at #3: return(res[1:3, ])
# Browse[2]> 
res
# [1] 6
```

("debug at" shows the next line to be executed, so we have not yet run `return(...)`.) With this, we can see that `res` -- which we *think* should be a `data.frame` -- is just a single number. Huh. Now look back at the code and figure out what happened. To me (and in this simple example), it's clearly `x[1,2,3]` that's a problem.

Comment: I tried using requiredOutcomes <- caremeasures[,c(11,17,23)] and the code broke down again. Here's the error: "Error in `[.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 4) : undefined columns selected "
I can't see how I can link the selected columns to  "arrangedData" according the outcome given as input.

Comment: It would help to know how you are calling your function and with what data. Please [edit] your question and add the output from `dput(head(careneasures))` and how you call `rankhospital`.